# How to check if an element is only child of type?

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a functionality where every child element has a button that removes that element from the DOM. When there is only one such element left I need it to remove the parent as well.

The problem is that the parent sometimes has before and after elements present, so the check has to take that in to account and probably has to be based on the type of element I am after, namely div.

So I am basically after `div:only-of-type` but the javascript version, non jquery.

I am imagining something like this:

```
if (target.parentNode.onlyOfType()) {
    //do seomthing
}
```

Comment: why not `document.querySelectorAll('div').length === 1`?

Comment: It really was that simple! I am very much in early stages of learning js so my imagination for solutions is quite limited. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of `children` of the `parentNode` based on which you can you can remove the parent element of the targeted element.

**Demo:**

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
Array.from(btns).forEach(function(b){
  b.addEventListener('click', function(target){
    if (this.parentNode.children.length == 1) {
      this.parentNode.remove();
    }
    else alert('Has other child, can not be deleted');
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="">Container 1
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
  <label>Some Other</label>
</div>
<div class="">Container 2
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="">Container 3
  <label>Some Other</label>
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
</div>
```

If you want to check the type then you can use `querySelectorAll()` like the following way:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
Array.from(btns).forEach(function(b){
  b.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var type = this.type;
    if (this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(type).length == 1) {
      this.parentNode.remove();
    }
    else alert('Has other child with same type, can not be deleted');
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="">Container 1
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
  <label>Some Other</label>
</div>
<div class="">Container 2
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="">Container 3
  <label>Some Other</label>
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Delete</button>
  <button type="button" class="myClass">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Both of these work. And now i know that ParentNode.children seems to ignore before/after elements. Thanks.